# Embedded SVG in the PDF created using TCPDF turning grey scale

Tags: php, svg, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create a PDF file. However, some of the SVG files that I have and would like to use in this PDF turns into grey/ black in the output. If I open those SVG files in the browser or Adobe Illustrator it looks correct.

Code that I have used to create the PDF:

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);



// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/star.svg', $x=5, $y=5, $w='200', $h=200, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
$pdf->Output('example_012.pdf', 'I');
```

However, another SVG works absolutely fine. I have attached both the SVG file and PDF attachment.

SVG that don't work in PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kbj2200cw4hhrm/star.svg?dl=0

Output PDF: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn8pfpdmzx66a50/mypdf-star.pdf?dl=0

SVG that works correctly in PDF
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsr6f763n39wflt/tux.svg?dl=0

Output PDF:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hs4jo3dz3knyod/mypdf-tux.pdf?dl=0

Comment: You could include the images to the post so it would all be contained here.

Comment: how is that is tagged fabricjs too?

Comment: @Felix I've included them as a Dropbox link.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I've just removed the Fabricjs tag.

Comment: @tanayjha Yes, that's what I was referring to. What about when you delete them from your dropbox?

Comment: @Felix SVG attachment is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

One of several SVG features that TCPDF doesn't support is setting style characteristics via class names. For example, your star SVG's fill colors won't be used because they are set with a class.

For this particular case, export from Illustrator with inline styles or presentation attributes and it should work.

[Edit: As an addendum, there are numerous ways for an SVG to break in TCPDF. In general, simpler is better. TCPDF's SVG parser is reasonably capable, but far from complete, so some breaking is expected and this is why the option to rasterize with ImageMagick is avaiable.]